# Duplicate modifier for the method ClickPage in type ClickPage

Tags: java, selenium

i am trying to take baby steps to learn **page object model (POM)**. Here is my page class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class ClickPage {

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3[2]/a")
    public WebElement link;

    public  ClickPage(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void navigator(){    
        link.click();
    }
}
```

But in the in the constructor it complains with

```
Duplicate modifier for the method ClickPage in type ClickPage
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

From your example code block it is evident that you are trying to use `PageFactory` through POM in your work. When the `ClickPage` Class is called, the elements on the page are already initialized. Next you are again trying to initialize the elements through `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`. Hence the error **`Duplicate modifier for the method ClickPage in type ClickPage`**.

Here a few things needs to be addressed as follows:

1. Consider declaring the WebDriver instance globally.
2. Create a constructor for the WebDriver instance.
3. Your `ClickPage` Class will be looking like:

**ClickPage** Class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class ClickPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    //constructor
    public LoginPageNew(WebDriver ClickPageDriver)
    {
        this.driver=loginDriver;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/h3[2]/a")
    public WebElement link;

    public void navigator(){    
    link.click();
    }
}
```

4. Now you need to initialize the variables on `ClickPage` page while you run the tests. So from your test class `VerifyValidLogin` we will call the `initElements()` method as follows:

**VerifyValidLogin** Class:

```
    @Test (priority=0)
    public void click_a_page()
    {
        //Created Page Object using Page Factory
        ClickPage click_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ClickPage.class);

        //Call the method
        click_page.navigator();

    }
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Initelements method Pagefactory class initializes the variables marked with findby annotation with proxies. It does not initialise the class.